# Tkinter widget keeps expanding when changed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have an expanding frame in tkinter which opens opens up to reveal more widgets inside. However when I open up the frame it gets longer in the x axis, despite none of the elements inside being larger then the frame.

```
class ToggledFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, text="", *args, **options):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **options)

        self.show = tk.IntVar()
        self.show.set(0)

        self.title_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.title_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)

        ttk.Label(self.title_frame, text=text).pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=1)

        self.toggle_button = ttk.Checkbutton(self.title_frame, width=2, text='+', command=self.toggle,
                                            variable=self.show, style='Toolbutton')
        self.toggle_button.pack(side="left")

        self.sub_frame = tk.Frame(self, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1)

    def toggle(self):
        if bool(self.show.get()):
            self.sub_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=0)
            self.toggle_button.configure(text='-')
        else:
            self.sub_frame.forget()
            self.toggle_button.configure(text='+')

class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="PLACEHOLDER", color='grey'):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placeholder_color = color
        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.foc_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.foc_out)

        self.put_placeholder()

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

    def foc_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

    def foc_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.put_placeholder()

root = tk.Tk()
    
root.geometry("600x200")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

frame_1 = tk.Frame(root, pady=2, padx=2, width=200)
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')

t1 = ToggledFrame(frame_1, text='Button 1', relief="raised", borderwidth=1)
t1.pack(fill="x", expand=1, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="n")

text1 = EntryWithPlaceholder(t1.sub_frame, "text")
text1.pack( expand=1, pady=2, padx=2, anchor="n")
    
root.mainloop()
```

Image one is before the frame is expanded, image two is after the plus button has been clicked and the frame has been expanded.

[image: Unclicked Frame]

[image: Clicked Frame]

Is there any way to prevent this resizing of the frame?

Answer (score 0):

> despite none of the elements inside being larger then the frame.

This statement is not true. The `Entry` widget defaults to a width of 20 characters, which will make it wider than your frame. The solution is to set the width of the entry to something smaller (eg: 1), and then configure it to fill the frame (eg: `text1.pack(fill="x", ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

> despite none of the elements inside being larger then the frame.

This statement is not true. The `Entry` widget defaults to a width of 20 characters, which will likely make it wider than your frame. The solution I would choose is to set the width of the entry to something smaller (eg: 1), and then configure it to fill the frame (eg: `text1.pack(fill="x", ...)`)